# Forcing JAWS to read a block of text

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm working on improving accessibility for a website, and I'd like to force JAWS to read a block of text in order to help the user.

For example, I have a help icon link that pops up a help modal. This modal contains some helpful text. I want to be sure that this text is read to the user. I'd like to have a solution similar to a `div` where I can do something like:

```
<div class="ForceReadText">
  <p>Block of text to be read, that currently isn't being read.</p>
</div>
```

I'm not very familiar with JAWS, and my google-fu skills are failing me. I figured it'd be better to ask someone who might know how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: Need more context. Are you trying to have the modal interrupt whatever the user is doing? Have you looked at ARIA live regions?

Comment: @aardrian - basically the user should be looking through these help icons to allow them to navigate a table, and if they click one of these, it should read the content right away. I haven't looked at ARIA live regions. I've briefly looked at ARIA but I will do more research. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are describing, it sounds like you might want an ARIA live region. [MDN has an overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) that may be of use.

For a quick overview, a live region is great fit for real-time updates to a page, such as errors or alerts. A live region has the ability to interrupt whatever a screen reader is speaking in order to speak the message instead. A live region does not change the location of the focus on a page.

The trick will be understanding that a page really should have just one live region.

The other trick will be getting all your messages into one live region, though it is certainly do-able if your pop-up behaves like a tool-tip (just re-use it).

If it behaves like a modal, keep reading...

Now, all that being said, the previous answer (from @stringy) is probably a smarter approach as long as you have good focus management practices (necessary for a modeal). If you do not, then a live region may be a better fit (and maybe less jarring).

Either way, take a look at these patterns and see if one addresses your goal:

- [2.3 Alert](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#alert)
- [2.4 Alert and Message Dialogs](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#alertdialog)
- [2.9 Dialog (Modal)](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#dialog_modal)

Comment: I ended up using an alertdialog. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Forcing things is difficult and gives the appearance of rudeness. What I've done in the past for accessible modals is to make the icon that opens them a link, with the link pointing to the `id` attribute of the modal or its heading. If someone wants help, the click the link and are taken to the information (and will use the arrow keys to read the text); if not, they can just move on.

```
<a href="#modal-heading"><img src="icon.png" alt="More information"></a>
```